# Central Limit Theorem: Can not understand how to take the logartimus of Characteristic function

Tags: probability, quantum-mechanics, central-limit-theorem, statistical-mechanics

I am looking at a proof of the *Central Limit Theorem*  and I am  having some trouble understanding the following step:

We have the Characteristic funtion of a distribution $w(x)$:
\begin{equation}
\xi(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-ik)^n}{n!} \langle X^n \rangle 
\end{equation}

at some point in the proof the author says that he takes the exponential of the $ln$ of this function, and skipst the actual computation leaving me with:
\begin{equation}
\xi(k) = \exp[-ik \langle X \rangle  -\frac{1}{2}k^2(\Delta x)^2 + ...k^3 + ...]
\end{equation}

I am struggling to comprend what exactly has been done here,since i do not seem to work it appropriately with logarithmus prorpieties.
Can somebody help?

Comment: I recommend you to heck out the Taylor series expansion of the exponential.

Comment: I understand how to expand the exponential, what I do not understand is how to take the logarithmus of the series, but maybe I am ovelooking something simple

Comment: Hint: from the Ansatz $\xi(k)=\exp\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(ik)^n}{n!}c_n$, you can obtain simultaneous equations implying $c_0=0,\,c_1=\langle X\rangle,\,c_2=(\Delta x)^2$ etc. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant).

Comment: Nice, I had to take the expansion of log $\xi(k)$, It worked, thanks a lot!